# Change colors of statusline in haskell-vim-now

Tags: vim, vimrc, haskell

I am using haskell-vim-now, which has many features I like when editing Haskell. However, it also sets a colorscheme I do not like. In my ~/.vimrc.local I already resetted to the default colorscheme. However, the statusline still has some funny colors:

[image: statusline]

What are the names of the fields that are not white-on-black, and how can I reset them? I already tried

```
hi StatusLine guibg=black guifg=white ctermbg=black ctermbg=white
hi link StatusLine StatusLineNC
hi link StatusLine ModeMsg
hi link StatusLine MoreMsg
```

But that does not help.

Comment: `haskell-vim-now` is a script that replaces your `vimrc` with a 652-lines file, and installs 27 other plugins.  Perhaps the author of the script is better qualified to point you in the right direction, rather then some random people on SE?

Comment: Why did you gave ctermbg twice? Was it a typo?